# Loading php pages based on a condition

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I have an index.php file which has 2 included files

```
require("stats.php");
require("stats_encry.php");
```

1. stats.php which has some variable declarations.
2. stats_encry.php which has another set of variable declarations.

Now if a user just goes to index.php (by going to mysite.com/root/index.php) via search or directly I want the index to load stats_encry.php

But if the user goes to the index.php?auth=jHh87fBinJ0Nj1EcDPOPxeXQe I want the stats.php loaded instead of stats_encry.php

The idea is to prevent someone from seeing certain contents if they endup in the index.php page by accident. So if I give someone the specific url of the index file with a value added at the end he should be able to see the content (Which will be loaded via stats.php)

How do I do the index.php ? Thanks a lot for any help..

Comment: Just check if `$_GET['auth']` is set and has the correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check for `$_GET`:

```
if (isset($_GET['auth'])
{
  require 'stats_encry.php';
}
else
{
  require 'stats.php';
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a total newbie. what am i doing wrong?

<?php

$_GET['jHh87fBinJ0Nj1EcDPOPxeXQe']

require("stats.php");
require("stats_encry.php");

if (isset($_GET['jHh87fBinJ0Nj1EcDPOPxeXQe'])
{
  require 'stats_encry.php';
}
else
{
  require 'stats.php';
}


?>

Comment: @Gary Martin If your variable name is `auth` just use what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Do I have to delcare the auth value?

$auth="jHh87fBinJ0Nj1EcDPOPxeXQe"; 

is this correct?

Comment: @Gary Martin The `auth` value comes from the url.

Comment: I understand. Let me test this and get back to you :)